# Unit test: Could not find data file if it is inside a folder

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing

I am creating data driven unit testing method which uses `xml` to pass data. I have followed examples which are given in SO and MS website and created a method accordingly.

I have created one `xml` file inside a directory `data` in my project. So the path is `/data/d.xml`. I have set `Copy to Output Directory` property as `Copy always`.  The problem I am facing here is, the file is being copied to the directory `Debug\data\d.xml`, but, my unit test method is trying to find it in `Debug\d.xml`.

How to make my unit test method to find that file in `Debug\data\d.xml`  or  How to make my data file moved directly under `Debug` folder without moving it out of the `data` directory?
My unit test method is as follows,

```
    [TestMethod]
    [DeploymentItem("d.xml")]
    [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "/data/d.xml", "model", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
    public void GetCPCModelTest()
    {
        //some code
        Assert.IsTrue(model != null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to give full path using `Directory` from `System.IO` and find the path in the test setup.

Example (may not be accurate for you):

```
private string path;

[TestInitialize]
public void InitTest()
{
    string dir = Directory.GetParent(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).FullName;
    path = dir + "\\data\\d.xml";
}

[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem("d.xml")]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", path, "model", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
```

Comment: How to use this in unit test method? I am not reading `xml` file in code. This is something that unit test is doing.

Comment: Again, the path I created may not be suitable to you and you need to change it.

Comment: Can't use concatenation outside methods.

Comment: have you run your test with this?

Comment: I don't have data driven tests, but I used `[SetUp]` (`NUnit` parallel of `[TestInitialize]`) and I used the path concatenation in my tests.

Comment: If I use fields like this in `DataSource`, it will give some build error.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220943/how-to-pass-dynamic-objects-into-an-nunit-testcase-function)

Comment: It's not allowing me to pass runtime generated values. It is expecting `const` value.